# Is it possible to miss a Super Magical/Legendary chest?

Tags: clash-royale

As many of you know, the Super Magical and Legendary chests go in a cycle, one in each 500 chests randomly.

BUT, **what happens when these two chests land in the same spot of the cycle?** Is it even possible? Which chest gets to be won?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to miss a Super Magical Chest or Legendary Chest, they will have distinct spots in the chest cycle. You will always get one of each in each cycle. The chest cycle is just programmed in that way.

Even if your chest slots are full and you win games, the cycle stays locked until you earn your next chest

Answer (score 3):

They can't land in the same spot.. legendary and super magical can only land on minor chests like magical or giant or gold/silver .. the cycle will move only if you aquire a chest from it (it won't move if you lose or you win with full chest slots)